# Как организовать обновляющююся инлайн клавиатуру в телеграмм боте?

Tags: python-3.x, telegram-bot, inline

Как можно организовать обновляющуюся инлайн клавиатуру в телеграмм боте, например, как в @botfather.

Сейчас клавиатура приходит новым сообщением при переходе по разделам меню.

Comment: А бот ведь сам сможет отправить сообщение если знает id чата (пользователя)?

Comment: Для отправки сообщения боту надо знать всего лишь id чата и само сообщение. Проблема не в этом. Проблема в том что бот отправляет инлайн клавиатуру пользователю, после нажатия на кнопку боту возвращается callback_data, в зависимости от этого бот должен отправить другую клавиатуру. Сейчас он посылает каждую клавиатуру новым сообщением. Мне нужно что б редактировалась старая